# Using PyGithub basic script complains "No module named 'requests'"

Tags: python, github-api, pygithub

I am using PyGithub from https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub to try out the github API to collect data from my code repository.

I did the following to try install all that is needed.

```
sudo pip3 install PyGithub
sudo pip3 install requests
sudo pip3 install pipenv
pipenv run pip3 install requests
```

I am trying to run the following sample script:

```
import requests
import json
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/repos/django/django')
if(r.ok):
    repoItem = json.loads(r.text or r.content)
    print "Django repository created: " + repoItem['created_at']
```

But I keep getting the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you launching it with python3 or python? @AdeleGoldberg

Comment: I am launching python. The command is `python the_script.py`. But, `python -V` on my machine outputs `Python 3.6.2`

Comment: Try it using "python3 the_script.py" or 'sudo pip install requests' , also you can try one a python terminal and importing it.

Comment: Trying it on a python terminal also complains the same : `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'`

Comment: The problem I think is that you are using sudo for installing "pip3 install requests", try it without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to python3.8 and pip3.8 resolved the issue